# Determine a line with the length and the 2 know angle in 2 planes. R languag

Tags: r, plot, 3d, static, angle

How to draw a line in three dimensions by knowing its length and angle in relation to two planes?

The following is the sketch I drew. (I know the length of "oA", angle of a1 and a2)

By the way, are there any ways to statistically compare the mean angular difference of "oA"s and "oB"s?

Please use the R language.

[image]

edited：

I just used some simple geometric calculations, and I can get the coordinates of (X, Y, Z), but I really don't know how to group and compare the statistical differences of the angles of these lines in three-dimensional space

[image]

Comment: You've seen this [rgl lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26853717/using-rgl-to-plot-3d-line-segments-in-r)?

Comment: Thank you for your link, but i could just measure the angle and the length not the start-end point...